# Did Al Pacino say "I asked God for a bike..."?

Tags: quotes

I see many quotes affirming that Al Pacino once said

> I asked God for a bike but I know God doesn't work that way. So I stole a bike and asked God for forgiveness.

However, I have never found this audio, soundtrack, movie clip or anything.

Is it true that Al Pacino said this?

Answer (score 20):

No, Al Pacino did not say this.

The comedian Emo Philips claims it as his own in a Guardian Article from [September 2005 entitled "The best god joke ever"](http://www.theguardian.com/stage/2005/sep/29/comedy.religion) (Incidentally, the title does not claim *the quoted joke* as the best God joke ever)

> [...] possible effect if the British government goes ahead with its intention to outlaw "offensive" religious jokes [....] So I hope the ban never goes into effect. But in case it does, I had better seize this last glorious moment to tell the rest of my religious jokes. Here goes:
>
> When I was a kid, I used to pray every night for a new bike. Then I realised, the Lord doesn't work that way. So I just stole one and asked Him to forgive me... and I got it!

This was originally said as part of a show, reported as from 1985 and can be viewed on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qegPkqs6rFw#action=share&t=8). Comedians are *usually* careful to not rip-off someone else's jokes, so it is safe to assume this was his own material.

Comment: And, not part of the answer but fun nonetheless - google search for `the Lord doesn't work that way. al pacino` = 285,000 results. `the Lord doesn't work that way. emo philips` = 65,500 results. There's misattribution, and then there's MISATTRIBUTION!!!